# Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '...' to data type int

Tags: variables, user-defined-functions

```
declare   @EmployeeID INT
declare   @age       varchar(4)
   select      @age = 'birthdate'  
   select      @EmployeeID = 'BusinessEntityID'

select BusinessEntityID , Birthdate 
from AdventureWorks2016.HumanResources.Employee
where BirthDate=@age  and  BusinessEntityID= @EmployeeID
```

The error is:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 58 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'BusinessEntityID' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

Just put ID, not the string `'BusinessEntityID'`:

```
 select      @EmployeeID = 10
```